# How to cleanup on Observable created with the .create(OnSubscribe) method

Tags: java, rx-java

I have the following code, which creates a custom `Observable` using the `Observable.create(OnSubscribe)` method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subscription subscription = Observable
                .create(subscriber -> {
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            subscriber.onNext("tick! tack!");
                        }
                    };
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0L, 1000L);
                })
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        System.err.println("finishing");

        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

The Observable issues a string every second using a timer. When the user presses enter, the subscriptions is cancelled.

However, the timer is still executed. How can I cancel the timer? I guess there must be a hook somewhere, but I can't find it.

On .NET, the `create` method would return an `IDisposable` which I could be my implementation to stop the timer. I am not sure how to map it to RxJava, as its `subscribe` method is `void`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more declarative (and IMHO easier to read) solution would be to use the [`Observable.using`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#using%28rx.functions.Func0,%20rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Action1%29) method:

```java
Observable<String> obs = Observable.using(
    // resource factory:
    () -> new Timer(),
    // observable factory:
    timer -> Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                subscriber.onNext("tick! tack!");
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0L, 1000L);
    }),
    // dispose action:
    timer -> timer.cancel()
);
```

You declare how the dependent resource (the `Timer`) is created, how it's used to create an Observable, and how it's disposed of, and RxJava will take care of creating the timer on subscription and disposing of it on unsubscription.

Answer (score 3):

you can add code that will be called when you'll unsubscribe from the stream. To do this, you'll have to add a new `Subscription` to your `subscriber` in the `create` method :

```
 subscriber.add(new Subscription() {
                @Override
                public void unsubscribe() {
                     // stop the timer here
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isUnsubscribed() {
                     // is the stream unsubscribed ?
                    return false; 
                }
            });
```

Comment: Will this `Subscription` be the `Subscription` returned to me when `subscribe` is called? Or is it another one, which I don't have access to directly?

Comment: Also, what should the implementation of `isUnsubscribed` look like? Hardcoded `false`  is probably wrong? Is something like `subscriber.isUnsubscribed()` correct?

Comment: it won't be the same `Subscription`. 

the `isUnsubscribed` may looks like `isUnsubscribed() { return running; }` with running a boolean. Take a look to `BooleanSubscription` : it can create a subscription with the `isUnscurbribedCode` : `subscriber.add(BooleanSubscription.create(() -> timer.cancel()));`

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Is it 'canon' way in RxJava? Seems way more complicated than in .NET. Can the fact that one subscriber has two subscriptions (the 'standard' one and the one I create and add myself) break some behavior? Like only one subscription unsubscribed and the other not and the state being inconsistent and behavior undefined?

Comment: I guess I can answer my own questions now, after some investigation and code reading: the `Subscription` which gets returned (actually the `Subscriber` instance, as a `Subscriber implements Subscription`) maintains a list of `Subscriptions` (indirectly, via a `SubscriptionList` instance), and its `unsubscribe` method iterates over all of them and unsubscribes. So, the no matter how many subscriptions are added to a subscriber, they all get unsubscribed at the same time and the state will be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see whether the subscriber has unsubscribed before sending a new value to it. If it has unsubscribed, then stop the timer:

```
Subscription subscription = Observable
    .create(subscriber -> {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    // stop timer
                } else {
                    subscriber.onNext("tick! tack!");
                }
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0L, 1000L);
    })
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: There are [examples using this method on the RxJava wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/How-To-Use-RxJava), under "Creating an Observable via the `create( )` method".

Comment: To be honest, I don't think all of the examples there are good. For example: `50.times { i -> if (!aSubscriber.unsubscribed) { aSubscriber.onNext("value_${i}") } }` will still iterate 50 times no matter what, just won't call `doNext()` for some values. For now, I somehow consider the idea of a custom `Subscription` somewhat cleaner, even if more verbose.

Comment: Yeah, that is a bit gross.

Answer (score 2):

So a combo of the above will do the job:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Subscription subscription = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
                timer.cancel();
            }));
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
                        subscriber.onNext("tick! tack!");
                }
            };
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0L, 1000L);
        }).subscribe(System.out::println);

        System.err.println("finishing");

        subscription.unsubscribe();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
```

This is a more idiomatic RxJava example that does the same thing with a lot less code:

```
Subscription subscription = Observable
    .interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .map(n -> "tick! tack!")
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.err.println("finishing");
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: I know about the RxJava timers. The question was more general, about cleanup of any resource, I just used a timer because the introtorx.com page uses it as an example. Thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution and I found this code in RxAndroid:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/v0.24.0/rxandroid/src/main/java/rx/android/content/OnSubscribeBroadcastRegister.java

It look like you don't need to use `Observable.using` to accomplish your cleanup step. Instead, it seems, you can add another subscriber that will do your cleanup.

```
Observable .create(subscriber -> {
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          subscriber.onNext("tick! tack!");
      }
  };

  subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
    timer.cancel();
  }));

  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0L, 1000L);
})
```